# What does this statement do (bin and int expression)?

Tags: python

I have the following statement:

```
set_bit = bin(int('1',2) | (int('1',2))).count('1')
```

This is how I broke it down:

- `int('1',2)`: Convert the string '1' into *int* using base 2, so it'll be 1.
- `count('1')`: Basically count all instances where there is a one in the expression
- I understand that `bin` converts the *int* value into binary

My issue is what `int('1',2) | (int('1',2)` means.

Comment: I'm confused what this is trying to accomplish. `1 | 1` is `1`, then `count('1')` would again return `1`?

Comment: @cricket_007 it was in a hackerrank question, and the solution showed this method. But now that you mention that it is a bit 'or' statement, I do agree that it's redundant.